# How pgbouncer care about session parameters in transaction pooling mode

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer

i connect to Postgresql via JDBC through **pgbouncer** with **transaction pooling mode** enabled. As far as I know in this mode pgbouncer can share same connection for several client without breaking session. So several clients may work within a single session sequentially, one by another. The question is does pgbouncer care about reseting session parameters when it detach one client from a connection and attach another client to this connection?

In particular, my app get connection and then issues something like this:

```
executeQuery(connection,"select set_config('myapp.user','fonar101',false)");
..../*other actions*/
commit(connection);
```

After commit pgbouncer can detach my app from connection and get it back to its pool, right? So,

1. if I issue another statements after commit they will probably be
   executed within another session with incorrect values of session
   parameters
2. pgbouncer can attach another client to that connection
   and that client will proceed with again incorrect session settings

How does pgbouncer care about this things?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the opposite:

https://pgbouncer.github.io/config.html

> **transaction**
>
> Server is released back to pool after transaction finishes.

Which means that when you `SET SESSION` (default for SET), without specifying `SET LOCAL`, you change settings for all transactions that share the session in the pool...

Answer (score 0):

According pgbouncer docs it [doesnt support](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PgBouncer#Feature_matrix_for_pooling_modes) SET/RESET and ON COMMIT DROP for temp tables in transaction pooling mode.

Comment: This is not entirely true. See https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/155582596.4848118.1418225874525.JavaMail.yahoo%40jws100188.mail.ne1.yahoo.com